# Kaspersky is blocking my batch file

Tags: batch, blocking, kaspersky

I made a batch file that is seen as malicious by Kaspersky. How can I tell that it is an acceptable file? I've found how to add an exception, but I can only add `.exe`, not `.bat`.

Comment: please post your batch code here if possible..

its not wise to add exclusions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up an exclusion rule, rather than an exception.

See this Kaspersky article : [How to manage exclusion rules in Kaspersky Internet Security 2012](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208284276).